# Visual Basic Msgbox checking if one cell is multiple of other or not?

Tags: excel, vba

i am creating a user interacting form. i have two cells (assume A1 and B1). Now value of A1 is already defined and user has to enter value for B1 such that its a multiple of A1. Can i display a msgbox if he hadn't entered a multiple of A1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will run whenever `B1` is changed. If you want to just add it into the code for your UserForm that take the `if` command I have marked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        // THIS CHECKS B1 AS A MULTIPLE OF A1
        If Range("B1").Value Mod Range("A1").Value <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "B1 is not a multiple of A1!"
        End If
        // END OF CHECK

    End If
End Sub
```